# Memory leakage on event handling

Tags: javascript

I've been reading about memory leakages lately and haven't yet wrapped my head around all of it and have some questions regarding my own style of writing. Specifically, I'm not really sure if the way I handle events might be a source of leaking. Consider the following code

```
function Wrapper(text) {
    this.text = text;
    this.bindHandlers();
};

Wrapper.prototype.onClick = function (e) {
    alert(this.text);
};

Wrapper.prototype.bindHandlers = function () {
    var t = this, div = $('<div>' + this.text + '</div>');

    var reallyHugeArray = [1,2,3...]; // an array of 100000 elements for example

    div.click(function (e) {
        // all variables of the parent function are in scope for this function, including reallyHugeArray
        t.onClick(e);
    });

    $(document).append(div);
};

var a = new Wrapper('testString');

// had enough fun with the Wrapper, now let's nullify it
a = null;
```

As you can see, I like to use an anonymous functions as the event handler so that it would be more convenient to have access to instance specific variables (in this case `this.text` in the `onClick` function) and functions. However, if I understood correctly, having an anonymous function inside a function (as is the event handler), which has access to the local scope, disables the garbage collector from removing the local variables, therefore creating a leak.

So my question is whether this method of event handling can create memory leakages and if it does, is there any way to prevent it, but still have a similarily convenient way to access the instance variables and functions?

(Off-topic: a function inside a function inside a function makes Javascript sound like Inception)

Comment: Any circular references between JS and host objects can create memory leaks in IE6/7. This will not create leaks in _any decent browser_

Comment: You mean the function passed to `div.click` can’t be deleted by the garbage collector, right?

Comment: A function called `bindHandlers` which creates DOM nodes and appends them to the document is bad naming convention

Comment: @Gumbo I mean that the anonymous click handler has access to variable t (the whole Wrapper object), but also possibly really really big arrays etc (I'll change the code a bit). Now when for some reason I no longer need the Wrapper and define it to null etc, are the possibly huge variables being freed from the memory properly? Raynos: this is just a quick sample I threw together to better explain the question, not real code from a project, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Raynos, where's the circular reference here?

Comment: @davin there isn't any because jQuery avoids them and he doesn't access the DOM directly. I meant it more along the lines of that's the only memory leak you should care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular example, the anonymous click handler creates a function closure for the scope above it.  That means that the values of `t`, `div` and `reallyHugeArray` are maintained for the life of your anonymous click handler function.

This is not a really a memory "leak", but rather memory "usage".  It doesn't get worse and worse over time, it just uses the fixed amount of memory that those local varaibles `t`, `div` and `reallyHugeArray` occupy.  This is often an advantage in javascript programming because those variables are available to the inner function.  But, as you wondered, it can occasionally cause problems if you expected that memory to be freed.

In the case of references to other things (DOM objects or other JS variables), since these outer variables continue on, everything that they refer to also continues on and cannot be freed by the garbage collector.  In general, this is not a big problem.  Things that tend to cause problems are things that are done over and over as the web page is used or things that are done in some large loop with lots of iterations.  Something only executed once like this just uses a little more memory once and from then on the memory usage of the construct is constant.

If, for some reason, you were binding this event handler over and over again, creating a new function closure every time and never releasing them, then it could be a problem.

I find this construct in Javascript very useful.  I don't think of it as something to stay away from, but it is worth understanding in case you have references to really large things that you want to be freed, transient things that should be freed because you don't need them long term or you're doing something over and over again.  In that case, you can explicitly set local variables to `null` if you won't need them in the inner function to kill their references and allow the garbage collector to do it's thing.  But, this is not something you generally need to do - just something to be aware of in certain circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, but what happens when the last line when the instance is set to `null` is executed. Since there's a DOM element that's bound to the anonymous function, which refers to the Wrapper instance, I presume that the object is retained in memory since we have a reference to it. And then at some later time, if the bound div is removed from DOM, without the event handler removed, would the variables (t, reallyHugeArray) then get collected or would it remain in memory? (I know that jQuery does abstraction to prevent memory leaks, but let's say that I didn't use .remove())

Comment: Sorry, forgot the @jfriend00 before.

Comment: @Zanfa the original poster is automatically notified of replies, no need for @ in this case :)

Comment: When you set `a = null;`, you're partially releasing your JS reference to the DOM object.  If the object is in the DOM, then it won't be deleted because it's in the DOM.  If the object is not in the DOM, then it may be eligible for garbage collection if there are no other references to it.  The gray area comes when you have an event handler associated with the DOM object.  I don't know how jQuery works in this regard, but I have read that at least in some older browsers, an object that has an event handler attached to it won't get garbage collected.

Comment: In your specific case above, the object is in the DOM and the event handler is still alive so the function closure containing your local variables and the anonymous function should stay alive and not be deleted.